# using self.request.user in model queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using Django 2

I have a model within which I have written a queryset class to add the search function.

I want to display only those results which are associated with the authenticated user. For that I'm using `user=self.request.user` in filter in queryset

**Notes/model.py**

```
class NoteQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def authenticated(self):
        return self.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def search(self, query):
        lookups = Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(tags__icontains=query)
        return self.filter(lookups).authenticated().distinct()


class NoteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return NoteQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def search(self, query):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query)


class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, default='Untitled')
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    objects = NoteManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notes:update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In **Notes/views.py**

```
class SearchNoteView(ListView):
    template_name = 'notes/my_notes.html'
    context_object_name = 'notes'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        if query is not None:
            return Note.objects.search(query)
```

But this return errors as

```
AttributeError: 'NoteQuerySet' object has no attribute 'request'
```

As the error states, it is trying to locate `request` funtion withing the class.

**How can I use the `request` in the queryset class?**

Comment: Don't. Why would you want to do that? Do the filtering in the get_queryset method of the view, where you have access to the request.

Comment: because I may need this filter somewhere else, so I just want to write it once and call the function wherever is needed in context of `Note` model

Comment: But it's so trivial, I don't see the point of adding such a high level of coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to somehow pass the user object in:

```
class NoteQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def authenticated(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)
```

I think it's much clearer if you just directly use `filter`:

```
 Note.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).search(query)
```

Comment: used second one in my application.